# Store Post Requests Fields in Database using Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, post, lumen

I'm coding a small yet useful app to serve as an end-Point of HTML Forms, to avoid manually code every time I want to save Forms submissions into Database. Because of the nature of the app, I want to store all the POST's fields sent by the HTML form that sends the request.

This is my approach: 
- User in the app creates an endpoint to send form submissions every endpoint will be stored in a table called ENDPOINTS that will have 2 fields: endpoint_URL (plain text to create the HTML endpoint) | data sent (JSON text to receive every field sent, no matter if every submission has different fields) this way I can store all the information without altering the structure of the Database Table every time a new field is received.

-The app then can show an HTML table of the specific endpoint and the information received field and content.

My concerns are: 
-every submission (no matter if the submission comes from different endpoints) will be stored in the same database table, therefore it can create a huge list of registries on a single table. 
Every time the HTML table is created will need to take the JSON content of the database field and reconstruct the HTML table (instead of using the power of the database to this endeavor).

What do you think could be the best approach to accomplish this? I can think on make a new table every time an endpoint is created and this table will receive every submission of the propper endpoint, nonetheless using this approach needs the database to update the fields every time the form receives different fields from the same endpoint.

I'm using LUMEN Framework instead of plain PHP to focus on the logic of the app rather than security concerns.

Comment: This is a bit to broad for SO, if you have a problem with some specific code then we can help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NigelRen, just wanted to know what do you think is the best approach: a single table with multiple endpoints and multiple registers JSON encoded, or for every endpoint create a new table with "dynamic" fields populated with every form submission fields of that specific endpoint.